# Deploy ARM templates with DSC in VSTS - How to build?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an arm template with a DSC extension in VSTS. This easily works with visual studio 2017. I just right click the solution and deploy and all works smoothly. However in VSTS it always fails if I include the DSC?

This is what i do in steps in VSTS:
I have my code in a VSTS git repository
1) In VSTS I Go to Build&Release menu
2) Click on the NEW button
3) Select a Template - Empty Process
4) Click on Get Sources
5) Select This Project
6) For Repository I select the repository my Templates are stored
7) I select the relevant Branch im working with
8) Add a Task
9) Azure Resource Group Deployment
10)  I select my Azure Subscription
11) I select my resource group
12) Template Location - left at default which is Linked Artiifact (what is this?)
13) Template - I click on the 3 dots and point it to my repository where my template is in VSTS
14) Template Parameters - as above but point it to the azure parameters JSON file
15) Override template parameters, put my VMname in , Admin Name and Password, leave _artifactsLocation Blank and leave _artifactsLocationSasToken Blank
17) Default Agent queue - Hosted
18) Click save and queue

It the goes off and starts a build, after a short while the following error appears :
Im trying to deploy an arm template with a DSC extension in VSTS. This easily works with visual studio 2017. I just right click the solution and deploy and all works smoothly. However in VSTS it always fails if I include the DSC?

This is what i do in steps in VSTS:
I have my code in a VSTS git repository
1) Go to Build&Release from the VSTS menu
2) Click on the NEW button
3) Select a Template - Empty Process
4) Click on Get Sources
5) Select This Project
6) For Repository I select the repository my Templates are stored
7) I select the relevant Branch im working with
8) Add a Task
9) Azure Resource Group Deployment
10)  I select my Azure Subscription
11) I select my resource group
12) I select my location
13) Template - I click on the 3 dots and point it to my repository where my teamplate is
14) Template Parameters - as above but point it to the azure parameters JSON file
15) I then Queue and Build

The machines are built etc but the DSC doesn't deploy and i get the error below? Anyone advise?

> There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed. At
>   least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment
>   operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details. Details: Conflict: { "status": "Failed", "error": { "code":
>   "ResourceDeploymentFailure", "message": "The resource operation
>   completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.", "details": [ {
>   "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError", "message": "VM has reported a
>   failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error
>   message: \"The DSC Extension received an incorrect input:
>   Configuration.url is '/DSC/dsc.zip'. This is not a valid URL.\nPlease
>   correct the input and retry executing the extension.\"." } ] } }
>   undefined Task failed while creating or updating the template
>   deployment.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty obvious, you are trying to point the DSC extension to a local file. upload a file to some publicly available place and point the DSC extension to that url.